# jQuery Ajax request issue

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue in jQuery ajax request. Once I send request using ajax as post or even get. It keep adding NaNundefiened.  `clearNaNgreen`

[JavaScript];

```
$("#btnSubmit1").click(function() {
    var criminality = $('select#criminality option:selected').val();
    var color1 = $("select#color1 option:selected").val();
    var business = $("select#business option:selected").val();
    var color2 = $("select#color2 option:selected").val();
    var civil = $("select#civil option:selected").val();
    var color3 = $("select#color3 option:selected").val();
    var bankruptcy = $("select#bankruptcy option:selected").val();
    var color4 = $("select#color4 option:selected").val();
    var education = $("select#education option:selected").val();
    var color5 = $("select#color5 option:selected").val();
    var candidateID = $("input#choosecandidate_hidden").val();

    var dataString =    'criminality='+ criminality + '&color1=' + color1 + '&business=' + business
                        + '&color2='+ color2 + '&civil=' + civil + '&color3=' + color3  + '&bankruptcy=' + bankruptcy+
                        + '&color4='+ color4 + '&education=' + education + '&color5=' + color5+
                        + '&report_status='+ report_status + '&color9=' + color9+'&report_form_name=report_form1&candidate_id='+candidateID;
                        //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "report_submit_ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            alert('Form has been sumbmitted successfully');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

[HTML]

```
<form id="report_form1" class="form" name="report_form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Executive Summary:</legend>
        <table cellspacing="10" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Criminality/Integrity Check</b></td>
                    <td><select id="criminality" name="criminality">
                            <option value="clear">Clear</option>
                            <option value="verified">Verified</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_mijor">Verified with Major Discrepancy</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_minor">Verified with Minor Discrepancy</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select id="color1" name="color1">
                            <option style="color: green;" value="green">Green</option>
                            <option style="color: blue;" value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option style="color: yellow;" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                            <option style="color: red;" value="red">Red</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Highest Education Check</b></td>
                    <td><select id="education" name="education">
                            <option value="clear">Clear</option>
                            <option value="verified">Verified</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_mijor">Verified with Major Discrepancy</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_minor">Verified with Minor Discrepancy</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select id="color5" name="color5">
                            <option style="color: green;" value="green">Green</option>
                            <option style="color: blue;" value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option style="color: yellow;" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                            <option style="color: red;" value="red">Red</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Second Profession Reference Check</b></td>
                    <td><select id="employment_check_2" name="employment_check_2">
                            <option value="clear">Clear</option>
                            <option value="verified">Verified</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_mijor">Verified with Major Discrepancy</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_minor">Verified with Minor Discrepancy</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select id="color7" name="color7">
                            <option style="color: green;" value="green">Green</option>
                            <option style="color: blue;" value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option style="color: yellow;" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                            <option style="color: red;" value="red">Red</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Report Status</b></td>
                    <td><select id="report_status" name="report_status">
                            <option value="clear">Clear</option>
                            <option value="verified">Verified</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_mijor">Verified with Major Discrepancy</option>
                            <option value="verified_des_minor">Verified with Minor Discrepancy</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select id="color9" name="color9">
                            <option style="color: green;" value="green">Green</option>
                            <option style="color: blue;" value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option style="color: yellow;" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                            <option style="color: red;" value="red">Red</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" name="btnSubmit1" value="Update">
</form>
```

here is the exact post I am getting

```
bankruptcy  undefinedNaNundefined
business    undefined
candidate_id    78
civil   undefined
color1  green
color2  undefined
color3  undefined
color5  greenNaNundefined
color6  undefined
color8  undefinedNaNclear
color9  green
criminality clear
education   clear
employment_check_2  clearNaNgreen
professional_reference  undefined
report_form_name    report_form1
```

As you can see, it generates such funny words. Any solution ?

Comment: Wow, you need to look into [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [jQuery.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: Also, for select elements, you do not need to do `$('select option:selected').val()` to get the selected value. You simply need to do `$('select').val()`.

Comment: Have you posted the entire html?I can't find select #color2,color3 etc.If they don't exist you will get undefined error

Comment: Thanks, actually I did it then I thought this was problem:)

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors return defferent elements than you expect. As result in some cases you get undefined or NaN (not-a-number) values sometimes concateneted togeter due to way how multiple values are combined.

I'd strongly recommend getting using JavaScript debugger in your browser (usually available by F12)  and checking results of every $(....) expression.

Answer (score 1):

check it here... http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/5RF6j/

some elements are missing on what you had given to us so it creates undefined

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use jQuery.serializeArray(). suggested by @ jaredhoyt, it is much more ieasy. It saved a lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#btnSubmit1").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert($('form#report_form1').serialize());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "report_submit_ajax.php",
                data: $('form#report_form1').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert('Form has been sumbmitted successfully');
                }
            });

            //return false;
        });​
```

for live deom see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/5RF6j/1/

for reference see this link : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/